# List versioning detect field level changes

Tags: list, event-receivers, versioning, version-history

I need to detect changes with each on each item update, )but i don't want to use the before, after properties )

My question is:

If i enable list versioning can i diff 2 versions to detect changes, what would be the performance impact? (storage, versions retrieval)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which technique you plan to use:

- Event Handlers - use ItemUpdating having properties object contains
  the collections BeforeProperties and AfterProperties that helps you
  to find out what has changed for your item,  i.e. compare properties.BeforeProperties[].ToString() with properties.AfterProperties[].ToString(). You can also modify the value of the fields in AfterProperties to affect what is actually stored in the list.
- SPD Workflows - use the Activity "Wait for field change" and the you could compare the 2

If you need to handle it across versions use something similar to

```
 if ((item.Versions!= null) && (item.Versions.Count > 0))
        {
                     SPListItemVersionCollection versions = item.Versions;
//work with through the colection

}
```

Comment: What is the performance hit on versions?

Comment: Haven't really benchmark it, but you actually retrieving ListItems

Comment: Actually that is already optimized upon extraction of versions per item, but is worth running some benchmarking if you really do a lot of operations on versions